# C# Applying dataGridView Cell Value to DateTimePickerObject

Tags: c#, datagridview

normally i apply the string values like this:

```
numID.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

but to insert it to a datetimepickerobject and change his value, I cant just use .Value like this:

```
 numStartDate.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value;
```

How should I do this? 
thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type is `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value`?

If this type of `DateTime`, then do the cast:

```
(DateTime)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value
```

If this type of a `String`, then do the following:

```
DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

PS: BTW, better use real data source, not DataGridView.Rows.